# What was this 80's sci-fi horror movie about a plasma-draining villain?

Tags: story-identification, horror, vampire

OK so for the longest time I thought this was the villain from Big Trouble in Little China, b/c he had this parasitic quality to him (old man drained energy from young girl to maintain himself), but that's not it. I distinctly remember a scene with numerous people, maybe all women maybe not, being physically drained of a yellowish fluid (implication that its plasma, not blood?), by some villain.* I had somehow confused this with Phantasm as well, but that's not even thematically related -  although related by timeframe. This aired on UPN (guessing) in the Chicago area in early/mid-90s. Was probably released in the 80's. Thx!

- Oh yah, so the plasma was being drained mechanically, into IV bags, not directly with fangs or something. That was one of the things that stood out about it, the creepily pseudo-medical nature.

Comment: [*Not of This Earth*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095756/) has an old man who drains plasma from people. Could that be it?

Comment: Very odd little film, and closest I've seen so far! But no, definitely not it.

Comment: There was also a 1995 remake which, potentially at least, could have aired during the "mid 90's".  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114004/

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you may be looking for [Lifeforce](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089489/).

> The space shuttle Churchill is assigned to observe the Halley's Comet
>   under the command of Col. Tom Carlsen. They see a strange form
>   attached to the comet and Carlsen goes with a team to investigate.
>   They find three humanoid life forms in caskets and they bring them to
>   the Churchill. However, Earth loses contact with the shuttle and the
>   Space Research Center sends another spacecraft to search the
>   Churchill. They find the crew dead and the shuttle burnt and one
>   rescue pod missing. They bring the humanoids to Earth and soon Dr.
>   Hans Fallada and his team discover that the Space Girl is a sort of
>   vampire and drains the life force from people transforming them into
>   zombies. When the authorities find that Col. Tom Carlsen has survived,
>   they summon him to explain what happened in the Churchill. Carlsen
>   tells an incredible story about the three aliens and he teams up with
>   Col. Colin Caine trying to save mankind from the evil vampires from
>   the space.

Warning: [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qej5nlRb9VM) is NSFW

Comment: There are also a couple [tag:life-force] questions on the site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please can you add some more detail about this film, e.g. by quoting from the link you provide? Link-only answers tend to be discouraged here, since if the link goes dead the answer becomes essentially useless. You might like to check out [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394) on answering story-ID questions.

Comment: Hmmm... Lifeforce. Maybe. But the IV bags seem unfamilur.

Comment: Thank you for the first attempt! I don't think this is it, the trailer didn't ring any bells, except maybe for the people in scrubs. I may need to watch it to make sure. I really do remember this featuring "pseudo-medical vampirism," and I remember people hooked up to tubing, for the purposes of draining plasma (?)

Answer (score 0):

This has some similarity to *I Come In Peace*.

This movie had a very human-looking alien who came to Earth to obtain drugs that he sold back home.  His method was to administer (a huge overdose of) heroin to his victims, and then use a syringe and long needle inserted into the brain (via the back of the neck, where the spinal cord enters the skull) to harvest the resulting endorphins as the victim died from the overdose.

He was being hunted by another alien, and one of them (I think it was the drug harvester) had a weapon that looked like a folding metal Frisbee and cut like a power saw.

The title was derived from the alien's line; he didn't actually speak English, as I recall, but had phonetically memorized a single phrase: "I come in peace."

Answer (score -1):

think its called dark angel or i come in peace.

Comment: Can you describe how this movie (or movies) matches the description?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Come_in_Peace